# Contents of large file getting corrupted while reading records sequentially

Tags: linux, go

I have a file, with around 85 million json records. The file size is around 110 Gb. I want to read from this file in batches of 1 million (in sequence). I am trying to read from this file line by line using a scanner, and appending these 1 million records. Here is the code gist of what I am doing:

```
var rawBatch []string
batchSize := 1000000

file, err := os.Open(filePath)
if err != nil {
    // error handling
}

scanner = bufio.NewScanner(file)

for scanner.Scan() {
    rec := string(scanner.Bytes())
    rawBatch = append(rawBatch, string(recBytes))

    if len(rawBatch) == batchSize {
        for i := 0; i < batchSize ; i++ {
            var tRec parsers.TRecord
            err := json.Unmarshal(rawBatch[i], &tRec)
            if err != nil {
               // Error thrown here
            }
        }
        //process
        rawBatch = nil
    }
}
file.Close()
```

Sample of correct record:

```
type TRecord struct {
    Key1         string            `json:"key1"`
    key2         string            `json:"key2"`
}

{"key1":"15","key2":"21"}
```

The issue I am facing here is that while reading these records, some of these records are getting corrupted, example: changing a colon to semi colon, or double quote to #. Getting this error:

```
Unable to load Record: Unable to load record in:
 {"key1":#15","key2":"21"}
invalid character '#' looking for beginning of value
```

Some observations:

1. Once we start reading, the contents of the file itself get corrupted.
2. For every batch of 1 million, I saw 1 (or max 2) records getting corrupted. Out of 84 million records, a total of 95 records were corrupted.
3. My code is working for for a file with size around 42Gb (23 million records). With a higher sized data file, my code is behaving erroneously.
4. ':' are changing to ';'. Double quotes are changing to '#'. Space is changing to '!'. All these combinations, in their binary representations, have a single bit difference. Any chance that we might have some accidental bit manipulation?

Any ideas on why this is happening? And how can I fix it?

Details:

- Go version used: go1.15.6 darwin/amd64
- Hardware details: Debian GNU/Linux 9.12 (stretch), 224Gb RAM, 896Gb Hard disk

Comment: Is the file being updated while it's being read?

Comment: That occasional, very rare 1 bit change suggests hardware failure (memory, processor cache, hard disk). I do recommend to test it on another computer.

Comment: @Flimzy yes. File gets updated while reading. I printed 'rec' immediately after Scanner.Bytes(). I could see corrupted records

Comment: So some other process is continually appending to the file?  Or is the file being actively updated (i.e. in the middle of the file)?

Comment: No other processes in my code are running. The contents are randomly getting corrupted. Not appended.

Comment: Are the errors always in the same place, same records? i.e. have you tracked/logged the byte-index of the stream? Does changing the batch size (say halving it) make a difference in the error location in the stream?

Comment: @icza your suggestion worked. Can you suggest any way to identify and detect what hardware failure it could be?

Comment: @SarthakAgarwal There are many test applications. First I recommend a memory test. Many BIOS  comes with memory test, so you may check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @icza in the comments,

> That occasional, very rare 1 bit change suggests hardware failure (memory, processor cache, hard disk). I do recommend to test it on another computer.

I tested my code on some other machines. The code is running perfectly fine now. Looks like this occasional rare bit change, due to some hard failure, was causing this issue.